# How can I filter RDD rows based on an external Array() of ids

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to execute the following lines of code but in a much larger RDD. Apparently, I get a heap size error when `a` is very large. How can I make this work? `p` is usually small.

```
val p = Array("id1", "id3", "id2");
val a = sc.parallelize(Array(("id1", ("1", "1")), ("id4", ("4", "4")), ("id2", ("2", "2"))));
val f = a.filter(x=> p contains x._1);
println(f.collect().mkString(";"));
```

Comment: Try [broadcasting](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables) `p`.  I don't know if this will solve your problem as it seems to be tied to the size of `a`, but it is good practice in general.

Comment: nice idea. so, I did `val p_b = sc.broadcast(p); val f = a.filter(x=> p_b contains x._1);`but unfortunately I get the following error `<console>:62: error: value contains is not a member of org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast[Array[String]] val f = a.filter(x=> p_b contains x._1);`

Comment: It should be `p_b.value` because you have to dereference the broadcast variable.

Comment: If your usecase if check for `contains` use a `Set` which optimizes such operation.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is not the filter or the small array, but the attempt to `collect` a large RDD which will effectively send all data to the driver, probably exhausting the driver's available memory.

What happens to the string afterwards? What's probably needed is another method to store the results of the filter computation.

Another note: if the main usecase of the small dataset is `contains`, consider using a Set instead of an `Array`, as `contains` is amortized O(1) on Sets and O(n) on arrays.